# How to change the build directory of a Hudson job?

Tags: hudson

My C: drive is full. I wish to move the builds folder from the job to another location. I can cheat with the help of the JUNCTION utility to redirect the original builds folder, but I am interested to know if there is the Hudson way to do it right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option (under Advanced Project Options) to choose a custom workspace in the hudson job. You can put the entire path there. This could be on your D or E or whatever other drive you want to use. You can do this for every job, and have a different workspace for each one.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I've just come across the same issue. This [blog post](http://ingorichter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html) was very helpful.

It is possible to change the default workspace and build folders for the whole server, not just per project.

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Advanced

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Just make another install of Hudson on a different drive and/or server and copy the job. The only think you have to take care of, is to look for hard coded paths in your batch scripts. See [Hudson documentation](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson)

Comment: 'another install' isn't quite right since it's not a reinstall, it's just a move of the working directories, not of the application itself.  But the pointer to the manual is the right answer.

Comment: I was actually suggesting to move the whole install. Don't know what the changes are if you want to move the whole Hudson install folder. My suggestion was based on the assumption that the jobs are always in the Hudson home folder. Since he runs Hudson on a Windows server, he at least needs to uninstall and install the Hudson service when he moves the location of the Hudson server. In order to have a clean working system, my suggestion was to install Hudson again from scratch at the location and just copy the job folder from the old to the new location.